# Columns Count in Google Sheets? VBA for Example

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, multiple-columns

Is there a way in JavaScript/Google Sheets to set a range based on the column count? If i were to Debug.Print myRange.Address it would be $A$4:$M$4.

```
Sub testGoogleSheets()
 Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Range("A4", Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the script:

```
function adder()
 {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
   var yourRange = sheet.getRange("A4");

   var yourLastColumn=sheet.getRange("A4:4").getLastColumn();
   var yourLastRange=sheet.getRange("A4").offset(0, yourLastColumn-1)
   var rsltRange1 = yourLastRange.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.PREVIOUS);       
   Logger.log(rsltRange1.getA1Notation());
   var rsltRange2 = sheet.getRange("A4:" + rsltRange1.getA1Notation());      
   Logger.log(rsltRange2.getA1Notation());

 }
```